# Jupyter notebook's response is slow when the codes have multiple lines

Tags: python, performance, jupyter-notebook

I have a question for the jupyter notebook.

When I copied and pasted 663 lines of a python code to the jupyter notebook,
it shows the much lower response than the notebook which has just a few code lines.

Have anyone experienced this issue?
Anyone knows the solution?

Comment: Well.. I just copy and past the python code lines, then I get slow response of the jupyter notebook. The code is for running the tensorflow, it means the main code of network.

Answer (score 0):

Without any information about your code is really difficult to give you an answer. 
However try to keep you output under control. Too much output to generate with a single run can overkill the kernel. 
Moreover, it makes not much sense to run in a single cell almost 700 lines of code, are you sure you're using the right tool?
Sometimes a piece of code could slow all the session, if you split your execution in smaller pieces, over multiple cells you will find what is really your bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your notebook and then click on the link after you execute the cell. Then you can track progress of what's running and see which statements are causing it to be slow. You could also split the code up into multiple cells to see where slow down is occurring.

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
#sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc =SparkContext()
spark_url = sc.uiWebUrl
display(HTML('''
<p>
    <br />Spark connection is ready! Use this URL to monitor your Spark application!
</p>
<p>
    <a href="{spark_url}">{spark_url}</a>
</p>'''.format(spark_url=spark_url)))
```

Comment: when I execute your codes, I got error as below:
NameError: name 'SparkContext' is not defined

Comment: Try updated code now. I replaced line 2 with 
`from pyspark import SparkContext
sc =SparkContext()`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. And sorry for late response.